# Record local camera feed in AppRTC audio/video call android with out using MediaProjection api

Tags: android, android-camera, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I had use AppRTC Demo to make audio/video call. It is working fine, What I want to achieve is to record only local camera feed of AppRTC call in android rather than recording entire screen using MediaProjection api. It would be great help if you provide any solution on this?

Comment: Hi @shwettak-ramteke, did you manage to solve this? I am trying to achieve the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why you ask this question? Video chat with camera is default behavior of AppRTC. MediaProjection will be used only when you manually change the setting in Settings.

Comment: I want to record only local camera feed during ongoing video call and store in sd card

Comment: So it's not related with MediaProjection. To record, just use MediaRecorder by feeding the Surface of webrtc renderer.